# IDEA Algorithm key is making incorrect decryption text

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am implementing IDEA encryption algorithm, and need to encrypt some text from a file, decrypt, and write it to output file.
But lets consider running an encryption sample as follows:

I am encrypting every 8 bytes(characters)[64-bit total] and the problem apparently is key related.
I am generating a 128-bit key using the following method

```
key=random.getrandbits(128)
```

**Algorithm run sample:**

```
plain_text = 'HiStackO'
# IDEA Example
cryptor = IDEA()  # Initialize cryptor with 128bit key
cipher_text = cryptor.encrypt(plain_text)
deciphered_text = cryptor.decrypt(cipher_text)
print(
    "Original text = {0}\nEncryption key = {3}\nCiphered text = {1}\nDeciphered text = {2}".format(plain_text, cipher_text, deciphered_text, cryptor.key))
```

Outputs:

```
Original text = HiStackO
Encryption key = 190198366819106713251143891094816949033
Ciphered text = 21ad870e1a262894
Deciphered text = HiStackO
```

Another run with different randomly generated key:

```
Original text = HiStackO
Encryption key = 139562249838113732045629763230225557471
Ciphered text = 6b547bde7d2b852
Deciphered text = „uÆ¹ç
```

For the above sample about every 5/6 runs gives you this incorrect result, it can vary with different plain texts...
What am I missing? I couldn't find any specific constraints for key generation for the algorithm
One weird thing is that almost every article/book on the web speaks about swapping steps 12 13 (11,12 here) for every round except the last round
But the method never worked, only this(swapping at only last half round)

Encrypt/decrypt + calculating cipher code:

```
ROUNDS = 9
def calculate_cipher(self, sub_keys, text):
    X = text
    K = sub_keys # 9 lists one for each round 8*6subkeys + 4 for the last half round

    step = ['0'] * 14
    for i in range(0, ROUNDS - 1):
        # Input print
        # print("Round [" + str(i + 1) + "] BIN input " + str(X))
        # print("Round [" + str(i + 1) + "] DEC input " + str([int(x, 2) for x in X]))
        # print("Round [" + str(i + 1) + "] HEX input " + ' '.join([str(hex(int(x, 2)))[2:] for x in X]))
        # Sub Key print
        # print("Round [" + str(i + 1) + "] BIN sub-key " + str(K[i]))
        # print("Round [" + str(i + 1) + "] DEC sub-key " + str([int(k, 2) for k in K[i]]))
        # print("Round [" + str(i + 1) + "] HEX sub-key " + ' '.join([str(hex(int(k, 2)))[2:] for k in K[i]]))
        step[0] = (self.mul(X[0], int(K[i][0], 2)))
        step[1] = (self.add(X[1], int(K[i][1], 2)))
        step[2] = (self.add(X[2], int(K[i][2], 2)))
        step[3] = (self.mul(X[3], int(K[i][3], 2)))
        step[4] = (self.xor(step[0], step[2]))
        step[5] = (self.xor(step[1], step[3]))
        step[6] = (self.mul(step[4], int(K[i][4], 2)))
        step[7] = (self.add(step[5], step[6]))
        step[8] = (self.mul(step[7], int(K[i][5], 2)))
        step[9] = (self.add(step[6], step[8]))
        step[10] = (self.xor(step[0], step[8]))
        step[11] = (self.xor(step[2], step[8]))
        step[12] = (self.xor(step[1], step[9]))
        step[13] = (self.xor(step[3], step[9]))

        X = [step[10], step[11], step[12], step[13]] 

    """X1 * K1
       X2 + K2
       X3 + K3
       X4 * K4"""
    X = [step[10], step[12], step[11], step[13]]
    result = []
    result.append(self.mul(X[0], int(K[ROUNDS - 1][0], 2)))
    result.append(self.add(X[1], int(K[ROUNDS - 1][1], 2)))
    result.append(self.add(X[2], int(K[ROUNDS - 1][2], 2)))
    result.append(self.mul(X[3], int(K[ROUNDS - 1][3], 2)))

    cipher = ''.join([str(hex(int(x)))[2:] for x in result])
    #print("Final Cipher/Decipher: " + cipher + "\n---------------")
    cipher = '0' * (16 - len(cipher)) + cipher
    return cipher  # Encrypted/decrypted Hex string

def encrypt(self, plain_text=''):
    plain_text = get_pt_bin_block_list(plain_text)#Converts every byte to 
binary (8 bytes) and then combines each 2 making list divided to 4 cells 16 bit each(each cell contains the int value of the combination of both chars binaries)
        print(plain_text)
        return self.calculate_cipher(self.enc_sub_keys, plain_text)

def decrypt(self, cipher_text=''):
    cipher_text = get_cipher_block(cipher_text)
    res = self.calculate_cipher(self.dec_sub_keys, cipher_text)
    res = ''.join('0' * (16 - len(res))) + res
    print("Decrypted cipher: " + res)
    return ''.join([chr(int(''.join(c), 16)) for c in zip(res[0::2],res[1::2])])    

**Operations**
    self.mul = lambda x, y: (x*y) % (2**BLOCK_SIZE+1)#int(np.mod(x * y, 2 ** BLOCK_SIZE + 1))
            self.add = lambda x, y: (x+y) % (2**BLOCK_SIZE)#int(np.mod(x + y, 2 ** BLOCK_SIZE))
            self.xor = lambda x, y: x ^ y
```

Comment: Most likely there's a bug in your `decrypt()` method.

Comment: Decrypt function is the same as the encryption but only with decryption subkeys derived from the original key, I'm really wondering why in every about 10 runs 1 fails.. I still can't find the issue

Comment: It's very simple: without code it's almost impossible to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have added code, the implemenation i'm following is similar to this mentioned here https://github.com/davidmigloz/IDEA-cipher/blob/8cb81e1cb2abdfad3c1317984b70cc59f6a043ee/src/main/java/com/davidmiguel/idea_cipher/crypto/IdeaCipher.java (same method for generating decryption keys)

Comment: I don't think you're handling leading zeros correctly on the hex representation of your bytes of cyphered data - note that your two cyphertexts are of different length, that shouldn't be possible here.

Comment: @jasonharper I have already extended the cipher to 16 hex digits as you can see before the return in calculate_cipher function cipher = '0' * (16 - len(cipher)) + cipher , I forgot to edit the examples, will do now, but still having the same issue it didn't help

Comment: Extending the ciphertext with zeros at the start is not even vaguely the same as having the zeros *where they belong* inside the ciphertext.

Comment: Right! how did I miss this, I extended the results list cells to 4 hex digits each and it worked. thanks alot